# Automisation of creating new variables based on the distribution of other variables in the data

Tags: r, data.table

I have data as follows:

## EDIT:

## Sample of Original Data

```
DT <- structure(list(Abbreviation = "AK", date = "1/31/2011", month = "01", 
year = "2011", c1 = "P", male = 12288, female = 6107, c4 = 2, 
upto22 = 870, from22to24 = 1441, from25to34 = 5320, from35to44 = 3568, 
from45to54 = 4322, from55to59 = 1539, from60to64 = 886, over65 = 451, 
c20 = 0, hispanic = 771, non_hispanic = 17458, c42 = 168, 
native = 4856, asian = 791, black = 611, hawaii = 289, white = 11209, 
c48 = 641), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

## Melted sample of Orginal Data

```
DT <- structure(list(Abbreviation = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), date = c("1/31/2011", "10/31/2011", 
"11/30/2011", "12/31/2010", "4/30/2005", "2/28/2011", "3/31/2011", 
"4/30/2011", "5/31/2011", "6/30/2011"), year = c("2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2010", "2005", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011"
), c1 = c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"), 
    State = c("Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", 
    "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska"), month = c("01", 
    "10", "11", "12", "04", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"), total = c(18395, 
    10654, 14113, 16248, 14029, 17915, 17152, 15543, 13325, 11637
    ), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("male", "female", "c4", "upto22", "from22to24", 
    "from25to34", "from35to44", "from45to54", "from55to59", "from60to64", 
    "over65", "c20", "hispanic", "non_nispanic", "c42", "native", 
    "asian", "black", "hawaii", "white", "c48", "c49", "c50", 
    "c87", "c88", "c89", "c90", "c91", "c92", "c93"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(12288, 5863, 8500, 10508, 8860, 12060, 11594, 9997, 
    8158, 6294)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

    Abbreviation       date year c1  State month total   variable value
 1:           AK  1/31/2011 2011  P Alaska    01 18395       male 12288
 2:           AK 10/31/2011 2011  P Alaska    10 10654     female  5863
 3:           AK 11/30/2011 2011  P Alaska    11 14113     upto22  8500
 4:           AK 12/31/2010 2010  P Alaska    12 16248 from22to24 10508
 5:           AK  4/30/2005 2005  P Alaska    04 14029   hispanic  8860
 6:           AK  2/28/2011 2011  P Alaska    02 17915      asian 12060
 7:           AK  3/31/2011 2011  P Alaska    03 17152      black 11594
 8:           AK  4/30/2011 2011  P Alaska    04 15543      white  9997
 9:           AK  5/31/2011 2011  P Alaska    05 13325       male  8158
10:           AK  6/30/2011 2011  P Alaska    06 11637       male  6294
```

The column `variable` has three groups of variables. These are `sex`, `age` and `ethnicity`. All of the groups add up to (more or less) the same total. So `male + female == total`, `black + white + asian == total` etc. What I would like to do is create new variables, such as `asian_male_upto22`, which would be the amount for asian, multiplied with the ratio of males to the total and the ratio of the respective age group to the total.

I am looking for a way to automise this process, but I am stuck figuring out how.

I was thinking about first assigning the variables to groups (`A <- c("male", "female")`), from there calculating the ratios per group, but it all seems a bit messy.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This will likely give you unrepresentative data. Lets say 80% of Asian males in Alaska are over 60 (Just making this up), You are proposing to distribute them according the the total % of population by age group, not the % population of that age group. Do you have access to more detailed census data?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Daniel. I am aware of the implications of doing this. But I would still like to know how to do it..

Comment: Is this the original dataset? It looks as if the data have been reshaped from wide to long format using `melt()`. If so I suggest to melt using *multiple measure* columns, see the vignette https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html and `?patterns`.

Comment: @Uwe It was, will try that tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Also, please, can you post data for all attributes of sex, age, and ethnicity, for *one* month and *one* state. The actual mix-up makes it difficult to verify that totals sum-up and computed shares/ratios/percentages give the desired result. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe I have added the unmelted data for on month for one state.

Comment: The `c` variables are by the way the respective NA's for the columns before. So `c4` is the count for which `sex` is NA. Also note that, the data distinguishes between race and ethnicity (hispanic, non-hispanic).

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the posted dataset: Shouldn't *non-nispanic* read *non-hispanic*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a challenging question. This is what I came up with (but I am sure there is room for improvement).

If I understand correctly, the dataset in wide format contains 4 *variables* `sex`, `age`, `race`, and `ethnicity` where, e.g.,  `sex` can assume the *values* `female`, `male`, or `NA`, and so on. Columns 6 to 26 contain the *counts* for each `value`. The *variables* are not included but need to be added to construct groups of *values*. [As mentioned by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406588/automisation-of-creating-new-variables-based-on-the-distribution-of-other-variab#comment110436782_62406588), the columns `c4`, `c20`, `c42`, `c48` contain the `NA` counts which add to the counts of the preceeding columns.

The processing includes several steps. The first part of steps will preprocess the data, the second part will create the new variables.

For creation of the new variables, there are two approaches:

- by a `cross join`
- or recursively by using `Reduce()`.

#### Preprocessing

(1) Create a *look-up table* to associate the columns and *values* with the *variable* they belong to.

```
lut <- data.table(value = names(DT))[
  , variable := value %>% 
    shift() %>% 
    like("c\\d{1,2}") %>% 
    cumsum() %>% 
    add(1L) %>% 
    extract(c("id", "sex", "age", "race", "ethn"),. )][]
lut
```

> ```
>            value variable
>  1: Abbreviation       id
>  2:         date       id
>  3:        month       id
>  4:         year       id
>  5:           c1       id
>  6:         male      sex
>  7:       female      sex
>  8:           c4      sex
>  9:       upto22      age
> 10:   from22to24      age
> 11:   from25to34      age
> 12:   from35to44      age
> 13:   from45to54      age
> 14:   from55to59      age
> 15:   from60to64      age
> 16:       over65      age
> 17:          c20      age
> 18:     hispanic     race
> 19: non_hispanic     race
> 20:          c42     race
> 21:       native     ethn
> 22:        asian     ethn
> 23:        black     ethn
> 24:       hawaii     ethn
> 25:        white     ethn
> 26:          c48     ethn
>            value variable
> ```

(2) Coerce character `date` to numeric date to get rid of the redundant `year` and `month` columns for brevity. In addition, numeric date is more flexible for ordering or plotting.

```
DT[, date := as.IDate(date, "%m/%d/%Y")]
```

(3) Reshape the dataset from wide to long format, thereby dropping columns `year`, `month`, and `c1`. (Please do not confuse the parameters `value.name` and `variable.name` of the `melt()` function with my definition of *variable* and *value*.)
(4) Append the matching *variable* to each *value* by an *update join*.
(5) Replace the obfuscating *values* `c4`, `c20`, etc. by `NA`
(6) Append the total for each group (including the `NA` counts).

```
long <- 
  melt(DT[, !c("year", "month", "c1")], id.vars = c("Abbreviation", "date"),
       value.name = "count", variable.name = "value")[
         lut, on = .(value), variable := i.variable][
           value %like% "c\\d{1,2}", value := NA][
             , total := sum(count), by = .(Abbreviation, date, variable)][]
long
```

> ```
>     Abbreviation       date        value count variable total
>  1:           AK 2011-01-31         male 12288      sex 18397
>  2:           ZZ 2011-01-31         male 12298      sex 18427
>  3:           AK 2011-01-31       female  6107      sex 18397
>  4:           ZZ 2011-01-31       female  6117      sex 18427
>  5:           AK 2011-01-31         <NA>     2      sex 18397
>  6:           ZZ 2011-01-31         <NA>    12      sex 18427
>  7:           AK 2011-01-31       upto22   870      age 18397
>  8:           ZZ 2011-01-31       upto22   880      age 18487
>  9:           AK 2011-01-31   from22to24  1441      age 18397
> 10:           ZZ 2011-01-31   from22to24  1451      age 18487
> 11:           AK 2011-01-31   from25to34  5320      age 18397
> 12:           ZZ 2011-01-31   from25to34  5330      age 18487
> ... 
> 31:           AK 2011-01-31       native  4856     ethn 18397
> 32:           ZZ 2011-01-31       native  4866     ethn 18457
> 33:           AK 2011-01-31        asian   791     ethn 18397
> 34:           ZZ 2011-01-31        asian   801     ethn 18457
> 35:           AK 2011-01-31        black   611     ethn 18397
> 36:           ZZ 2011-01-31        black   621     ethn 18457
> 37:           AK 2011-01-31       hawaii   289     ethn 18397
> 38:           ZZ 2011-01-31       hawaii   299     ethn 18457
> 39:           AK 2011-01-31        white 11209     ethn 18397
> 40:           ZZ 2011-01-31        white 11219     ethn 18457
> 41:           AK 2011-01-31         <NA>   641     ethn 18397
> 42:           ZZ 2011-01-31         <NA>   651     ethn 18457
>     Abbreviation       date        value count variable total
> ```

#### Create new variables by a *cross join*

(7) Create the names of the *new variables* by a *cross join* `CJ()`. The cross join will also include `Abbreviation` and `date`

```
new_vars <- 
  long[!is.na(value), CJ(Abbreviation, 
                         date, 
                         ethn = .SD[variable == "ethn", value], 
                         sex = .SD[variable == "sex", value], 
                         age = .SD[variable == "age", value],
                         unique = TRUE)][
                           , new.var := paste(ethn, sex, age, sep = "_")][]
new_vars
```

> ```
>      Abbreviation       date   ethn    sex        age                 new.var
>   1:           AK 2011-01-31 native   male     upto22      native_male_upto22
>   2:           AK 2011-01-31 native   male from22to24  native_male_from22to24
>   3:           AK 2011-01-31 native   male from25to34  native_male_from25to34
>   4:           AK 2011-01-31 native   male from35to44  native_male_from35to44
>   5:           AK 2011-01-31 native   male from45to54  native_male_from45to54
>  ---                                                                         
> 156:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white female from35to44 white_female_from35to44
> 157:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white female from45to54 white_female_from45to54
> 158:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white female from55to59 white_female_from55to59
> 159:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white female from60to64 white_female_from60to64
> 160:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white female     over65     white_female_over65
> ```

(8) Reshape `new_vars` to long format. This is required because the origial dataset has been reshaped to long format as well.

```
lnv <- melt(new_vars, id.vars = c("Abbreviation", "date", "new.var"))
lnv
```

> ```
>      Abbreviation       date                 new.var variable      value
>   1:           AK 2011-01-31      native_male_upto22     ethn     native
>   2:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from22to24     ethn     native
>   3:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from25to34     ethn     native
>   4:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from35to44     ethn     native
>   5:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from45to54     ethn     native
>  ---                                                                    
> 476:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from35to44      age from35to44
> 477:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from45to54      age from45to54
> 478:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from55to59      age from55to59
> 479:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from60to64      age from60to64
> 480:           ZZ 2011-01-31     white_female_over65      age     over65
> ```

(9) Append `new.var` by right joining `lnv` with `long`.
(10) Aggregate by `Abbreviation`, `date`, and `new.var`, thereby multiplying the counts and dividing by totals (in order to get shares).

```
long[lnv, on = .(Abbreviation, date, variable, value)][
  , .(new.count = prod(count)/first(total)^2), by = .(Abbreviation, date, new.var)]
```

> ```
>      Abbreviation       date                 new.var new.count
>   1:           AK 2011-01-31      native_male_upto22 153.38579
>   2:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from22to24 254.05623
>   3:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from25to34 937.94527
>   4:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from35to44 629.05803
>   5:           AK 2011-01-31  native_male_from45to54 761.99238
>  ---                                                          
> 156:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from35to44 720.79330
> 157:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from45to54 872.68769
> 158:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from55to59 312.04830
> 159:           ZZ 2011-01-31 white_female_from60to64 180.50050
> 160:           ZZ 2011-01-31     white_female_over65  92.86912
> ```

#### Alternatively: Create new variables *recursively* using `Reduce()`

Steps (7) to (10) can be replaced by recursively joining *subsets*.

If done manually this will look like:

```
long[!is.na(value) & variable == "ethn"][
  long[!is.na(value) & variable == "sex"], on = .(Abbreviation, date), allow.cartesian = TRUE,
  .(Abbreviation, date, value = paste(value, i.value, sep ="_"), count = count * i.count / i.total)][
    long[!is.na(value) & variable == "age"], on = .(Abbreviation, date), allow.cartesian = TRUE,
    .(Abbreviation, date, value = paste(value, i.value, sep ="_"), count = count * i.count / i.total)]
```

First, the subset for *variable* `ethn` is joined with the subset for *variable* `sex` (outer join) thereby computing the first part of the new variable name and the new count partially. Then the temporary result is joined with te subset for *variable* `age` thereby computing the new variable name and the new count, finally.

This can be written in a more general way as

```
join_fct <-   function(x, y) {
  x[y, on = .(Abbreviation, date), allow.cartesian = TRUE,
    .(Abbreviation, 
      date, 
      value = paste(value, i.value, sep ="_"), 
      count = count * i.count / i.total)]
}

Reduce(join_fct, 
       lapply(c("ethn", "sex", "age"), 
              function(x) long[!is.na(value) & variable == x])
)
```

> ```
>      Abbreviation       date                value      count
>   1:           AK 2011-01-31   native_male_upto22 153.385786
>   2:           AK 2011-01-31    asian_male_upto22  24.985205
>   3:           AK 2011-01-31    black_male_upto22  19.299571
>   4:           AK 2011-01-31   hawaii_male_upto22   9.128602
>   5:           AK 2011-01-31    white_male_upto22 354.057100
>  ---                                                        
> 156:           ZZ 2011-01-31 native_female_over65  40.280090
> 157:           ZZ 2011-01-31  asian_female_over65   6.630570
> 158:           ZZ 2011-01-31  black_female_over65   5.140554
> 159:           ZZ 2011-01-31 hawaii_female_over65   2.475082
> 160:           ZZ 2011-01-31  white_female_over65  92.869365
> ```

This approach is quite flexible as the number and order of *variables* can be changed easily, e.g.,

Reduce(join_fct,
lapply(c("race", "sex"),
function(x) long[!is.na(value) & variable == x])
)

> ```
>    Abbreviation       date               value      count
> 1:           AK 2011-01-31       hispanic_male   514.9779
> 2:           AK 2011-01-31   non_hispanic_male 11660.8090
> 3:           ZZ 2011-01-31       hispanic_male   521.2318
> 4:           ZZ 2011-01-31   non_hispanic_male 11657.9728
> 5:           AK 2011-01-31     hispanic_female   255.9383
> 6:           AK 2011-01-31 non_hispanic_female  5795.2930
> 7:           ZZ 2011-01-31     hispanic_female   259.2596
> 8:           ZZ 2011-01-31 non_hispanic_female  5798.6518
> ```

#### Data

The OP has provided on row of the original dataset (in wide format)

```
DT <- structure(list(Abbreviation = "AK", date = "1/31/2011", month = "01", 
                     year = "2011", c1 = "P", male = 12288, female = 6107, c4 = 2, 
                     upto22 = 870, from22to24 = 1441, from25to34 = 5320, from35to44 = 3568, 
                     from45to54 = 4322, from55to59 = 1539, from60to64 = 886, over65 = 451, 
                     c20 = 0, hispanic = 771, non_hispanic = 17458, c42 = 168, 
                     native = 4856, asian = 791, black = 611, hawaii = 289, white = 11209, 
                     c48 = 641), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

However, to verify the code works as expected, I need a second row. So I have appended a second row by:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbind(DT, DT)
DT[2, (6:ncol(DT)) := lapply(.SD, `+`, y = 10), .SDcols = 6:ncol(DT)]
DT[2, Abbreviation := "ZZ"]
DT
```

> ```
>    Abbreviation      date month year c1  male female c4 upto22 from22to24 from25to34
> 1:           AK 1/31/2011    01 2011  P 12288   6107  2    870       1441       5320
> 2:           ZZ 1/31/2011    01 2011  P 12298   6117 12    880       1451       5330
>    from35to44 from45to54 from55to59 from60to64 over65 c20 hispanic non_hispanic c42 native
> 1:       3568       4322       1539        886    451   0      771        17458 168   4856
> 2:       3578       4332       1549        896    461  10      781        17468 178   4866
>    asian black hawaii white c48
> 1:   791   611    289 11209 641
> 2:   801   621    299 11219 651
> ```

Comment: Hi @Uwe, this is absolutely amazing.. I had no idea it was so complicated, my apologies. I hope you at least had some fun solving this. I think you forgot to add the code for step 9 and 10 by the way.

Comment: Yes, it was quite a challenge, indeed. Perhaps, there might be other, less verbose approaches. I have added the missing code for step 9 and 10 - thank you for reporting.