# No applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I while ago, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406588/automisation-of-creating-new-variables-based-on-the-distribution-of-other-variab) question.

The data used was as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
DT <- structure(list(Abbreviation = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), date = c("1/31/2011", "10/31/2011", 
"11/30/2011", "12/31/2010", "4/30/2005", "2/28/2011", "3/31/2011", 
"4/30/2011", "5/31/2011", "6/30/2011"), year = c("2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2010", "2005", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011"
), c1 = c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"), 
    State = c("Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", 
    "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska"), month = c("01", 
    "10", "11", "12", "04", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"), total = c(18395, 
    10654, 14113, 16248, 14029, 17915, 17152, 15543, 13325, 11637
    ), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("male", "female", "c4", "upto22", "from22to24", 
    "from25to34", "from35to44", "from45to54", "from55to59", "from60to64", 
    "over65", "c20", "hispanic", "non_nispanic", "c42", "native", 
    "asian", "black", "hawaii", "white", "c48", "c49", "c50", 
    "c87", "c88", "c89", "c90", "c91", "c92", "c93"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(12288, 5863, 8500, 10508, 8860, 12060, 11594, 9997, 
    8158, 6294)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

And the answer involved, this code:

```
lut <- data.table(value = names(DT))[
  , variable := value %>% 
    shift() %>% 
    like("c\\d{1,2}") %>% 
    cumsum() %>% 
    add(1L) %>% 
    extract(c("id", "sex", "age", "race", "ethn"),. )][]
```

Which should create the following data:

> ```
>            value variable
>  1: Abbreviation       id
>  2:         date       id
>  3:        month       id
>  4:         year       id
>  5:           c1       id
>  6:         male      sex
>  7:       female      sex
>  8:           c4      sex
>  9:       upto22      age
> 10:   from22to24      age
> 11:   from25to34      age
> 12:   from35to44      age
> 13:   from45to54      age
> 14:   from55to59      age
> 15:   from60to64      age
> 16:       over65      age
> 17:          c20      age
> 18:     hispanic     race
> 19: non_hispanic     race
> 20:          c42     race
> 21:       native     ethn
> 22:        asian     ethn
> 23:        black     ethn
> 24:       hawaii     ethn
> 25:        white     ethn
> 26:          c48     ethn
>            value variable
> ```

Where before this worked perfectly, now I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("extract_") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I have been breaking my head about what could have changed and why this error now occurs.

It would be great if anyone had an idea.

Comment: `could not find function "add"`. Did you forget to load `magrittr`?

Comment: I will add `library(magrittr)` to the post, but I did not forget to load it. Double checked, and still get the same error. Thank you for pointing it out:)

Comment: Your code is using `extract` from `tidyr` instead of `magrittr`. Try using `magrittr::extract` instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Shall I remove the post?

Comment: Probably add an answer yourself and keep the post.

Comment: That's what happens when you load a truck load of decencies when you can do everything with a single package (+ `magrittr` if reaaaaaaaally need the pipes).

Comment: @RonakShah Using `magrittr::extract` removes the error, but it does not create the desired solution anymore. Do you have any idea what is going on there?

Comment: fixed it by additionally using `magrittr::add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this case was, as was pointed out in the comments, that the wrong library was used to execute the code. The solution therefore is to specify the library in the code:

```
lut <- data.table(value = names(DT))[
  , variable := value %>% 
    shift() %>% 
    like("c\\d{1,2}") %>% 
    cumsum() %>% 
    magrittr::add(1L) %>% 
    magrittr::extract(c("id", "sex", "age", "race", "ethn"),. )][]
```